# SQL query including Distinct and AVG

Tags: sql

I have a table `PC` and I want to return average speed for distinct model and speed.

[image: Screenshot of PC table]

As you can see in the screenshot, there are two PCs with the same model and speed (1121-600). They should be counted as a single PC.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MODEL, SPEED 
FROM PC
```

I wrote this but couldn't return the average of speed

```
SELECT AVG(DISTINCT MODEL, SPEED) 
FROM PC
```

It's incorrect query but it was best I could do. THANKS

EDIT:

```
SELECT AVG(SPEED) 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT MODEL, SPEED 
     FROM PC)
```

That's wrong too.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  Please explain how the last query is wrong.  It appears to be doing exactly what you describe.  Also, show the results that you want.

Comment: Please explain how the last query is wrong.  It appears to be doing exactly what you describe.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes! but I didn't know the syntax that i should add a Alias after subquery. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could distinct using `group by` and then apply a `window function` (assuming your database supports it)

```
select distinct avg(speed) over ()
from pc
group by model, speed
```

Comment: what is ''over ()'' statement? Is it about the windows functions? why I get 6 rows (450
500
600
750
800
900) after i removed the "over()" statement.

Comment: @İrfanÇalışır Yes, once you have the distinct pairs of speed and model from the group by, over() will basically take entire column (window) of speed and calculate it's average. Window functions are applied after group by which is why this one avoids a subquery

Comment: @İrfanÇalışır . . . This is exactly the same as using `distinct` in a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT AVG(SPEED)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MODEL, SPEED
      FROM PC
     ) PC;
```

There is never a good reason to use `AVG(DISTINCT)`.  I wish the language did not allow it.

Comment: Why did you say that? Is it bad habit for clean code or what?

Comment: @İrfanÇalışır . . . I can think of no situation where `avg(distinct)` would produce a meaningful value and such a construct is the best way to arrive at the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the average speed of each PC, rather than their collective average, then modify Gordon's answer to:

```
SELECT MODEL, AVG(SPEED) as AVG_SPEED
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MODEL, SPEED
      FROM PC
     ) as PC
GROUP BY MODEL;
```

Careful though - if the duplicates are actually separate observations, then you might not want to eliminate them from your aggregation.

Sorry, dont have enough rep, otherwise I'd comment on Gordon's.